# Much worse performance with RBF kernel than linear in SVM in python scikit-learn

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, nonlinear-functions

I am performing some machine learning tasks using SVM. I suspect the data is non-linear so I also included the RBF kernel. I found that SVM with RBF kernel is MUCH worse than linear SVM. I wonder if I did something wrong with my classifier parameter specifications.

My code as follows:

```
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.svm import SVC

svm1 = LinearSVC() # performs the best, similar to logistic regression results which is expected
svm2 = LinearSVC(class_weight="auto") # performs somewhat worse than svm1
svm3 = SVC(kernel='rbf', random_state=0, C=1.0, cache_size=4000, class_weight='balanced') # performs way worse than svm1; takes the longest processing time
svm4 = SVC(kernel='rbf', random_state=0, C=1.0, cache_size=4000) # this is the WORST of all, the classifier simply picks the majority class
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With RBF try tuning your `C` and `gamma` parameters. Scikit-learn's grid search will help you.

Here is an example to get you started:

```
svc = SVC(...)
params = {"C":[0.1, 1, 10], "gamma": [0.1, 0.01, 0.001]}
grid_search = GridSearchCV(svc, params)
grid_search.fit(X,y)
```

Comment: You are correct, by turning the C and gamma the performance has drastically improved. I wonder if the SVM (with non-linear kernel) performs no better than SVM with linear kernel, does it mean the classes are linearly separable?

Comment: Try tuning your linear svm. No gamma for linear, only C. You might be surprised what becomes linear separable in a high dimension space.

Comment: In high dimension spaces linear svm usually does better. Low dimension spaces, RBF does better.

Comment: In high dimension, you mean the number of features, right? Could you explain or reference to why in high dimension, linear svm does better? Shouldn't the more dimensions there is, the harder it is to separate using straight line/plane?

Comment: Yes. By dimensions I mean the number of features. In high dimensional spaces, the distance between points becomes less meaningful, which is why a kernel is less meaningful. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality . Also in higher dimensional spaces, it often becomes easier to create a linear decision boundary.

Answer (score 1):

Following paper is a good guide for SVM users.

A Practical Guide to Support Vector Classification
http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf

In a nutshell, three points are essential to let SVM perform correctly.

- (1) feature preparation (feature scaling, feature categorization)
- (2) parameter tuning (coarse and fine-grained cross validation)
- (3) kernel selection (#features vs #instances)

Basic idea for (3) is to select the linear kernel if #features >> #instances. With small #instances, SVMs with non-linear kernels can be overfit easily.